# List Representation of Quoted Expressions in Scheme

Tags: list, scheme, quote

In Scheme, I'm running `(quote (+ 2 3)) returns (+ 2 3)`. From what I understood, the quote just told Scheme to not evaluate my expression for some purpose. I'm trying to make the list `(+ 2 3)` without the use of quote. So I tried: 
Typed: `(cons '+' (cons 2 (cons 3 '())))` 
Scheme's return:`(+ cons 2 (cons 3 (quote ())))`
- I don't understand why I got this return value. I was hoping for `(+ 2 3)`

Typed: `(cons '+' (2,3))` 
Scheme's return:`(+ 2 3)`
- I don't understand how this worked. So, is `(cons '+' (2,3))` the same as `(quote (+ 2 3))`?

Comment: You have too many quotation marks. You want `(cons '+ ...)`, not `(cons '+' ...)`.

Comment: @AlexisKing Oh I thought that I needed '+' to say that + is a character then '() to specify the NULL list

Comment: @AnonymousGal The `+` is a symbol. A character would be written as `#\+`. When you use two single quotes, the first one quotes the `+`-symbol, and the second quotes the following list.

Answer (score 0):

`'expression` is the same a `(quote expression)` and it becomes `expression` unevaluated.

When you write `(cons '+ '(cons 2 (cons 3 '())))` you are quoting both `+` and the second argument, `(cons 2 (cons 3 '()))`. The `'` has no end marker.

When displaying pairs a Lisp system will default to displaying pairs with a pair tail as a list if you wondered why it didn't turn into `(+ . (cons 2 (cons 3 (quote ()))))`

An implementation can choose how to display `'(quote ())` and `''()`. Mine show `'()` while yours show `(quote ())`. They represent the exact same so it's not really different in other things than the visualization.

`` `(1 , 2) `` is the same as `(list '1 2)` since you are `unquoting` `2`. Luckily for you it's a number and it always evaluates to itself. It might be that you though the comma was some sort of separation between elements, but it's not. It's just to simplify writing a large data structure where only a few elements are variable.

```
(define (test e)
  `(a list with ,e representing some wanted structure))

(test 'test) ; ==> (a list with test representing some wanted structure)
```